# Wamp Server - PHP 7.3.5 - composer problem - socket permission denied

Tags: php, cmd, composer-php, shell-exec

When I trying to execute composer update in php code:

```
    echo shell_exec('C:\\wamp64\\bin\\php\\php7.3.5\\php composer.phar update 2>&1');
```

I receiving below error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information The "https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Została podjęta próba uzyskania dostępu do gniazda w sposób zabroniony przez przypisane do niego uprawnienia dostępu. https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date Updating dependencies (including require-dev) [Composer\Downloader\TransportException] The "http://repo.packagist.org/p/doctrine/common%24fa721fd8e5b3fad736bae7f9 30f2e494ca31d45dfeb6ce0e1adddca4a869da53.json" file could not be downloaded : failed to open stream: Została podjęta próba uzyskania dostępu do gniazda w sposób zabroniony przez przypisane do niego uprawnienia dostępu. update [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--lock] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-suggest] [--with-dependencies] [--with-all-dependencies] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--apcu-autoloader] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--prefer-stable] [--prefer-lowest] [-i|--interactive] [--root-reqs] [--] []...
```

Comment: Your installation of PHP cannot open a connection to the internet.  Much more information about your environment is required.

Comment: PHP info - https://gist.github.com/pietrach/79f0d525f922082cc4d89015c261e484